Google Auth access token is becoming invalid, with Incremental Scopes
I am building a flutter mobile application (for IOS and Android platform), i want my users to first do google Signin and then provide incremental scopes (calendar/email) to my application.
But as soon as, i take incremental scopes my access token is becoming invalid, otherwise if i just remove the incremental scopes code the access token is working fine. (Even working if i take scopes along with Signin)
I am using, google_sign_in: ^6.2.2 package.
What am i doing wrong?
Attaching the code below:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:aad_oauth/aad_oauth.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/analytics/events.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/data/http/http.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/data/http/http_v2.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/features/home/controllers/calender_access_provider.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/main.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/services/analytics_service.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/services/one_signal_service.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/services/storage_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:havahavai/utilities/enums.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple.dart';

final authServiceProvider = Provider<AuthService>((ref) {
  return AuthService(ref: ref);
});

class AuthService {
  AuthService({
    required this.ref,
  });

  final ProviderRef ref;
  String? loginToken;
  Map<String, String?> tokensMap = {};

  Future<Map<String, String?>> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      var token = await StorageService()
          .initialize()
          .read(key: SecureStorageKeys.LOGIN_TOKEN.name);
      debugPrint("Token $token");

      
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(
        clientId: Platform.isIOS
            ? "CLIENT_ID"
            : null,
        serverClientId: Platform.isIOS
            ? "SERVER_CLIENT_ID"
            : null,
        scopes: [
          // 'email',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
        ],
        forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
      ).signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
          await googleUser?.authentication;

      if (googleUser == null || googleAuth == null) {
        throw FlutterError("Google sign-in failed");
      }

      final email = googleUser.email;
      final accessToken = googleAuth.accessToken;
      final idToken = googleAuth.idToken;
      final serverAuthCode = googleUser.serverAuthCode;

      debugPrint('---------------------------------------------------');
      debugPrint('Email : $email');
      debugPrint('Access Token : $accessToken');
      debugPrint('Refresh Token : $idToken');
      debugPrint("Server Auth Code : $serverAuthCode");
      debugPrint('---------------------------------------------------');

      tokensMap.addAll({
        'email': email,
        'accessToken': accessToken,
        'idToken': idToken,
        'serverAuthCode': serverAuthCode,
        'serviceProvider': 'gmail'
        // 'type': 'calendar' //gmail
      });

      return tokensMap;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }
  
  Future<void> logout() async {
    try {

      // await updateLogoutNotificationToken();
      await ref
          .read(storageProvider)
          .delete(key: SecureStorageKeys.LOGIN_TOKEN.name);
      await ref
          .read(storageProvider)
          .delete(key: SecureStorageKeys.CALENDER_ACCESS.name);
      await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
      await GoogleSignIn().disconnect();

      debugPrint(
          'Token and Google account signed out and disconnected successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Error signing out: $e');
    }
  }
}


